# Migration into RAILS 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I migrate from Rails 3.x to Rails 4.2

I have the following code:

```
Order.all :conditions => ["flagged = ? AND orders_id != ? AND (
  delivery_name = ? OR
  delivery_telephone = ? OR
  email = ? OR
  ((delivery_address IS NOT NULL AND delivery_address != '') AND delivery_address = ?) OR
  (remote_ip IS NOT NULL AND remote_ip = ?)
  )",
  true,
  self.orders_id,
  self.delivery_name,
  self.delivery_telephone,
  self.email,
  self.delivery_address,
  self.remote_ip,
]
```

and when I run the tests I get the following deprication:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#all is deprecated. If you want to
>   eager-load a relation, you can call #load (e.g. `Post.where(published:
>   true).load`). If you want to get an array of records from a relation,
>   an> you can call #to_a (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).to_a`). (called
>   from similar_flagged_orders at
>   /Users/fisnik/code/myr-admin/app/models/order.rb:173)

Any suggestions please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Order.where("flagged = ? AND orders_id != ? AND (
  delivery_name = ? OR
  delivery_telephone = ? OR
  email = ? OR
  ((delivery_address IS NOT NULL AND delivery_address != '') AND delivery_address = ?) OR
  (remote_ip IS NOT NULL AND remote_ip = ?)
  )",
  true,
  orders_id,
  delivery_name,
  delivery_telephone,
  email,
  delivery_address,
  remote_ip
)
```

Upgrade from 3.x straight to 4.2 is insane and inevitably you will struggle a lot to make things work.

[**Do it gradually**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-0-to-rails-3-1).

First upgrade to 3.2, then to 4.0, and only here you have 2 options - 4.1 and 4.2.

Also gradually upgrade your testing framework.